# How can I use basic authentication on a WCF endpoint hosted in IIS over SSL with json?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, authentication, iis

I've got a restful WCF service that's hosted in IIS served up over SSL using a WebHttpBinding and json.

The service now requires authentication/authorization. There appears to be lots of old information that may or may not still be relevant promoting different ways of achieving authentication, but none of them appear to apply to this specific blend of endpoint binding.

I've played with a bunch of different types of bindings and this appears relatively simple to achieve with SOAP based authentication, but not so with json. Most of the information points to the fact that authentication is usurped by IIS, but I've overcome that hurdle.

I'd like to use basic authentication like so (Example Fiddler request):

```
GET https://secure.dev.myco.local/api/users/v1/0b7478c5-d25a-4039-9cf4-614b2ef4e04d HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: secure.dev.myco.local
Authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6UEAkJHcwcmQh
```

I have the following service behavior configuration:

```
<behavior name="SslBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=*.dev.myco.local" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" />
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic" 
                                serviceAuthenticationManagerType="Test.Api.TestAuthenticationManager, Test.Api" />
</behavior>
```

binding definition:

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="ProductBinding">
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
  <binding name="UserBinding">
    <security mode="Transport" />
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

and service definition:

```
<service name="Test.Api.ApiService" behaviorConfiguration="SslServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://secure.dev.myco.local/api/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="products/v1" name="ProductService" contract="Test.Api.Product.V1.IProductService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProductBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ProductEndpointWebHttpBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="users/v1" name="UserService" contract="Test.Api.User.V1.IUserService" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UserBinding" behaviorConfiguration="UserEndpointWebHttpBehavior" />
</service>
```

My user accounts are to be held in a table in a database, and authentication passes off the credentials to an authentication provider that for all intents and purposes returns either an IIdentity, an IPrincipal or a boolean if the user authenticates. This will then be attached to the context as required. Because of this, I need my application to handle authentication and not just hand off authentication to IIS.

I am successfully able to access the credentials from the HTTP header and authenticate the user by deriving from the authentication manager and overriding the Authenticate method with the following example code - the IPrincipal is generated and attached to the context as I would expect:

```
public class TestAuthenticationManager : ServiceAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> Authenticate(ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy> authPolicy, Uri listenUri, ref Message message)
    {
        var requestProperties =
            (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];

        var rawAuthHeader = requestProperties.Headers["Authorization"];

        AuthenticationHeader authHeader = null;
        if (AuthenticationHeader.TryDecode(rawAuthHeader, out authHeader)) ;
        {
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(authHeader.Username);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] {});

            var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)
            {
                User = principal,
            };

            if (httpContext.User != null)
                return null;
        }

        SendUnauthorizedResponse();

        return base.Authenticate(authPolicy, listenUri, ref message);
    }

    private void SendUnauthorizedResponse()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"site\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Where I'm coming unstuck is that upon exiting the validate method, my service responds with the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The caller was not authenticated by the service.'. See
>   server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthenticationBehavior.Authenticate(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The service works fine if I remove the authentication reference from the configuration - as you'd expect, but the user is anauthenticated, and thus if I add any authorization to any of the service methods, it won't handle that piece.

The method appears to exit without error. Can anyone shed any light on why I'm getting this exception with this configuration? I've Googled until the cows come home and the information I find all relates to a limited number of variations of other configurations, but none for WebHttpBinding with Json hosted in IIS with SSL.

Comment: Can you post your webHttpBindingConfiguration ?

Comment: In your bindings, try to add  TransportClientCredentialType="Windows"

Comment: @Rom Eh This credential type doesn't make sense, it would require Windows Authentication in IIS and my user credentials are held in a customer database, not Windows.

Comment: Have you tried Basic ?

Comment: @Rom Eh: Yes, all of the transport credential types have IIS usurping authentication and IIS (near as I can tell) will only authenticate against Active Directory, which I don't want.

Comment: What kind of database do you use ? An AD-LDS ? or a custom one ?

Comment: User authentication is handled by a custom Authentication provider that returns a boolean corresponding with whether the user credentials are valid.

Comment: In you code, you use : Test.Api.AuthenticationManager, but your class is named : RestAuthenticationManager. Could it be that ?

Comment: When you call your service, can you debug (step by step) your custom authentication provider ?

Comment: Have you add <system.diagnostics> logs in your service ?

Comment: I doubt this line `if (httpContext.User != null) return null;` if the Authenticate method return Null as Authorization policy the Dispatcher will throw exception. Here in your case the condition is always `true` and so it always return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (httpContext.User != null) return null;` is the problem. if the Authenticate method return Null as Authorization policy the Dispatcher will throw exception.

Here the condition is always true and so it will always return null.You need to return a authorization policy instead of null.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was just the ticket.